# Rails: ActionController::Parameters#delete returns the value instead of key-value pair?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

According to Rails API [`ActionController::Parameters#delete`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-delete)

> Deletes and returns a key-value pair from `Parameters` whose key is equal to key. If the key is not found, returns the default value. If the optional code block is given and the key is not found, pass in the key and return the result of block.

However, when I extract the param from my class on rails and did a 
`.class`, it returns `Array` instead of `Hash`.

```
def create
    @var = myClass.new(param_function.except(:param1))
    weird = param_function.delete(:param5)
    puts weird.class
end

def param_function
    params.require(:my_class).permit(
      :param1,
      :param2,
      :param3,
      :param4,
      :param5 => []
    )
 end
```

delete, should return a hash with key being `param5` and value being an `array` of values, so `weird` should be a hash. However, it puts array as result.

Comment: @Stefan but then when you puts it, it returns an array of values only tho? As the API said, it should return something like this `[param5, val1,val2,]' so when I puts it, it should return 'param5','val1','val2'. However, it only returns 'val1','val2'. the key did not print out.

Comment: You are right, I've deleted my previous comment. The documentation is wrong (or at least very misleading). `delete` actually works like [`Hash#delete`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Hash.html#method-i-delete), i.e. it deletes the key-value pair and returns (just) the value.

Comment: You are probably looking for [`extract!`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-extract-21).

Comment: @aDev ruby does not have a `Hash#delete!` (delete is implied to be mutative so the bang would be redundant) so rails `HashWithIndifferentAccess#delete` works exactly the same way as `Hash#delete` as you can see [Here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html#method-i-delete) and `ActionController::Parameters` essentially just delegates this call as shown in the docs you presented. The docs are just incorrect

Comment: @engineersmnky yeah, I read that right after I post that comment. I have deleted it after realizing it was a wrong assumption. Thanks for the infor.